spark.write.saveAsTable not writing all the rows
Yesterday, I ran a simple spark code on ingesting a large table. The code was simple in that it did a
 dataframe = spark.read.format(datasource).(query).load()
I did a  dataframe.count  and it returned me some large amount of rows (say 10B)
I then write the dataframe to a new table using save as table and writemode to overwrite. The table didnt exist so it was created anew.
 dataframe.write.saveAsTable(tableName).mode('overwrite').partitionBy('somecolumn')
Then I do a
 df = spark.sql('select * from tablename')
and a  df.count  gives me rows lower than the 10B that I ingested - the difference is small  ( in tens of thousands) but I cannot seem to understand why there would be a difference - why wouldnt all the rows be ingested in the destination table.
Upon investigation, the rows that were missed are actual valid rows, they are not duplicates and do not seem to have a 'database some side process could be writing or deleting from the table' (missing rows are spread sporadically  across time whereas we add new rows by time and deletion would also indicate missing rows to be the oldest)
What am I missing here? Isnt a dataframe write supposed to be reliable to write all rows or throw an error if it cannot write some row (schema mismatch etc which shouldnt be the case here since we are writing as a new table) - how additionally should I investigate this?

based on my understanding, what you're describing doesn't seem possible. can you reproduce this behavior with dummy data or a smaller number of records?
